# I want remove list2 elements from list1 and return the list1

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java-8

I have two Lists

```
List<myObject> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("544");
list1.add("545");
list1.add("546");
list1.add("547");
list1.add("548");
list1.add("549");  

List<myObject> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("547");
list2.add("548");
```

**Now I want to remove list2 from list1 and return list1. so my final returning list will look like**

```
List<myObject> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("544");
list1.add("545");
list1.add("546");
list1.add("549");
```

**I want to do this in Java8. I did it in java7 and it works fine but I want this in Java8. can anyone help me?**

Comment: There's not a new way to do this that's *better* than the old way. `removeAll` is still the best way.

Comment: *I did it in java7 and it works fine* what did you do ?

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

You can use the `removeAll` method to remove the items of one list from another list.

To obtain the duplicates you can use the `retainAll` method, though your approach with the set is also good (and probably more efficient).

list1.removeAll(list2);

**Method 2**

You can use org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils and make all that you want in only one line.

```
List resultList = ListUtils.subtract(list, list2);
```

**Method 3**

For Java 8 you can use Streams :

```
List<Integer> diff = list1.stream()
                          .filter(i -> !list2.contains(i))
                          .collect (Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes, exactly the mismatch of return type was the issue that you have faced. I have tried this code for Integer and you are working on an Object.